# How to import multilanguage articles into Magento through SOAP?

Tags: php, magento, soap, import, internationalization

I'd like to import multilanguaged articles into Magento by using the provided SOAP interface. I am already able to do this for shops that only use a single language in their frontends.

But I like to do this for international shops, i.e. Magento stores with several store views. I know that the store view's ID is a parameter in the `catalogProductCreate` SOAP method. But I hesitate to transfer the complete product record twice using different store view IDs, as the Magento SOAP API is not really known for its speed. :-) To be honest, I cannot believe that it is necessary to create an article twice to display it in two languages.

Is there an easier way to import articles into multiple store views using SOAP? Both records only differ in the translated descriptive strings - prices, stock data, etc. are all the same. Does anyone know how Magento handles such situations?